# If any strings in a list match regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to check if any of the strings in a list match a regex.  If any do, I want to continue.  The way I've always done it in the past is using list comprehension with something like:

```
r = re.compile('.*search.*')
if [line for line in output if r.match(line)]:
  do_stuff()
```

Which I now realize is pretty inefficient.  If the very first item in the list matches, we can skip all the rest of the comparisons and move on.  I could improve this with:

```
r = re.compile('.*search.*')
for line in output:
  if r.match(line):
    do_stuff()
    break
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Why not use the builtin `any()`?  Eg: `if any(re.match(line) for line in output)`

Comment: @Jkdc becasue `any()` takes a list and converts each element into a `bool`, then evaluates the bool.  So in order to get it to the point that `any()` would be useful, I'd still have to do the regex match on every element.

Comment: @ewok: no, `any` takes something which is *iterable*.  jkdc's code uses a lazy generator expression, not a list.

Comment: @DSM.  The lazy generator was what I was looking for.  his initial comment didn't include that.

Comment: aside from using `any` i think you've just answered your question with your second attempt

Comment: @Jkdc the lazy generator there is what I was looking for.  add it as an answer

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the builtin `any()`:

```
r = re.compile('.*search.*')
if any(r.match(line) for line in output):
    do_stuff()
```

Passing in the lazy generator to `any()` will allow it to exit on the first match without having to check any farther into the iterable.

Comment: Any way to access the matched string using this method? I'd like to print it for logging purposes

Comment: IMHO, instead of `re.match` shouldn't it be `r.match` as OP has created a compiled regular expression object `r = re.compile('.*search.*')`

Answer (score 15):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can also capture a *witness* of an `any` expression when a match is found and directly use it:

```
# pattern = re.compile('.*search.*')
# items = ['hello', 'searched', 'world', 'still', 'searching']
if any((match := pattern.match(x)) for x in items):
  print(match.group(0))
# 'searched'
```

For each item, this:

- Applies the regex search (`pattern.match(x)`)
- Assigns the result to a `match` variable (either `None` or a `re.Match` object)
- Applies the truth value of `match` as part of the any expression (`None` -> `False`, `Match` -> `True`)
- If `match` is `None`, then the `any` search loop continues
- If `match` has captured a group, then we exit the `any` expression which is considered `True` and the `match` variable can be used within the condition's body

Answer (score 8):

Given that I am not allowed to comment yet, I wanted to provide a small correction to MrAlexBailey's answer, and also answer nat5142's question. Correct form would be:

```
r = re.compile('.*search.*')
if any(r.match(line) for line in output):
    do_stuff()
```

If you desire to find the matched string, you would do:

```
lines_to_log = [line for line in output if r.match(line)]
```

In addition, if you want to find all lines that match any compiled regular expression in a list of compiled regular expressions r=[r1,r2,...,rn], you can use:

```
lines_to_log = [line for line in output if any(reg_ex.match(line) for reg_ex in r)]
```

Comment: Yes, I do want to match with a list of regular expression.  Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

In reply to a question asked by @nat5142, in the answer given by @MrAlexBailey:
**"Any way to access the matched string using this method? I'd like to print it for logging purposes"**, assuming "this" implies to:

```
if any(re.match(line) for line in output):
    do_stuff()
```

You can do a for loop over the generator

```
# r = re.compile('.*search.*')
for match in [line for line in output if r.match(line)]:
    do_stuff(match) # <- using the matched object here
```

Another approach is mapping each match with the map function:

```
# r = re.compile('.*search.*')
# log = lambda x: print(x)
map(log, [line for line in output if r.match(line)])
```

Although this does not involve the "any" function and might not even be close to what you desire...

I thought this answer was not very relevant so here's my second attempt...
I suppose you could do this:

```
# def log_match(match):
#    if match: print(match)
#    return match  
if any(log_match(re.match(line)) for line in output):
    do_stuff()
```